# C# Нужна помощь с массивом

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms

Программисты, нид хэлп! У меня есть txt файл с данными:

```
Alpha 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
R 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
G 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
B 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
```

И мне надо сделать такой массив, с помощью которого я могу получить доступ к определённому числу, а не ко всей строчке.
Как реализовать такой массив?

UDP: Простите если мой вопрос слишком пустой, не умею нормально описывать то, что мне нужно

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не люблю аббревиатуру "хз".

Comment: Разбиваете строку на массив строк. Преобразуете элемент массива (строка-число) в число. Profit

Comment: @ArchDemon. Можете пожалуйста привести пример? А то мне как-то трудно понять как это всё делать

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split и https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number

Comment: `var result = File.ReadAllLines(...).Select(x=>x.Split());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

```cs
byte[][] data = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt")
    .Select(line => line.Split().Skip(1).Select(byte.Parse).ToArray())
    .ToArray();

// первый столбец R
byte red = data[1][0];
```